# dart2js: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<SVGAnimatedString> has no method 'split'

Tags: svg, dart, dart-editor, dart2js

I'm working on simple online building planner tool, which uses svg element (dart:svg library) as editor canvas. Development build works perfect in native Dartium VM, but after running dart2js I'm getting next error in any browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<SVGAnimatedString> has no method 'split'
```

Dart does't show any error while compiling to js. Error appears right after DOM loaded, so could it be dart2js translator issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AnimatedString](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_svg/AnimatedString.html) does not have a `split` method.

Perhaps you are facing [Issue 15787:    className instance variable of SvgElement is an SVGAnimatedString instead of a string in dart2js](http://dartbug.com/15787).

Comment: Thank you. Looks like this is dart2js bug. Any possible workarounds?

Comment: You can perhaps try with a type test `String value = s is AnimatedString ? s.animVal : s`

Comment: Error appears when trying to add class name actually, not reading it.